# Problem connecting to Oracle db inside heroku through a static IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, heroku, firewall

I'm writing a Rails application that needs to connect to an Oracle database inside a company firewall. Thus, i need to connect to their VPN or at least use a static IP address to make all my connections.

I've tried [Proximo](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/proximo) and [QuotaGuard](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/quotaguardstatic) without success. I make all required configs, but no matter what i do, the firewall says i'm trying to connect through my actual IP, instead of the static one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days trying, and a big help from the QuotaGuard guys, i solved it:

QuotaGuard works by overriding DNS lookup so my server connections goes to my local machine, where a process will redirect all traffic to my remote server, that will connect through the right IP.

But it seems like oracle drivers don't see this DNS changes, so it will make all the requests to the final server, who blocks my connection. All i did was point my database connection info to 127.0.0.1, so the `qgtunnel` app could send it to the final server.

It's working like a charm now.

So, my final setup was like:

`.qgtunnel` file

```
[qgtunnel.0]
accept = "127.0.0.1:3333"
connect = "HOST_ADDRESS:3333"
encrypted = false
transparent = true
```

`config/oracle_db.yml` file

```
default: &default
  encoding: utf8
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3333
  database: database
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASS'] %>

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

`Procfile` file

```
web: bin/qgtunnel bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```